# Windows 8 Enterprise update to 8.1 without reactivation

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

It is known that update Windows 8 Enterprise to 8.1 is not so easy. As I understood I must somehow download update immage, make bootable device and make procedure that is close to re install whole system.

All my colleagues told me that after update all programs was gone. Is that really so paint full?

Do I need reactivate windows or enter key for this purpose? I'm asking that because I have only activated Windows 8, but I haven't any keys or CD's.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install from the Store? Depending on the number of PCs, creating a new 8.1 image *is* the proper way, but for a handful of machines just installing from the Windows Store will update you without causing any data loss or re-entry of keys.

Comment: According to MS, it is not possible to install from Store Enterprise version

Comment: ...right...I forgot about that. An example of MS making things far more difficult than they need to be.